# Bootstrap fixed-top behaviour between PC and mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am comparing the fixed-top when in mobile and when in desktop. My code is below where I initially found in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/. The weird thing is in desktop.. The fixed navbar will go along in any part of the screen.. In my code below it is a 300px navbar and when I scroll horizontally it is there. But when I check in mobile view the `fixed` behaviour will not work anymore. Basically, it will not go along when I scroll horizontally. It will just stay on its original position.. Is there a way to make my nav in mobile behave the same as when in PC? Take note that when I say mobile, I am just using the mobile view in Chrome and Samsung S5

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <title>Fixed top navbar example for Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" style="width: 320px">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container" style="width: 3000px; max-width: 3000px">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how fixed to top navbar works. As you scroll, it will remain fixed to the top of your browser's viewport.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, So here is the solution for your problem, actually in your case you inner div is way more than body's width and your whole body has a scroll bar, and the position fixed works with the body.

So simple solution to make it work on mobile and desktop as well, just use your width item like that so it will not affect the scroller of the

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <title>Fixed top navbar example for Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" style="width: 320px">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container" style="overflow: auto;max-width: 100%;">
      <div class="jumbotron" style="width: 3000px; max-width: 3000px">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how fixed to top navbar works. As you scroll, it will remain fixed to the top of your browser's viewport.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.4.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

whole body.

I just made some small changes to your code, and now it will work on Desktop and mobile as well,

Comment: But is t there another approach? Overflowscroll is more of a cheat.. It's good to know why fixed-top behaves different between mobile and browser

Comment: haha, You removed the right answer tick, Although I did not help you to get the score, but in your scenario, you can not do without having a scroll in any inner section, if you have a problem removing the width from the main main container, then you can have a section as parent of it and give that height 100vh and overflow scroll or auto, and you do downvote this as well, 
There is no time for good.

Comment: No, actually this is good enough. I think I am just looking for more explanations. It feels really frustrating if the behaviour is different between browser and mobile